# Backup from server, folders to ftp and passing problems

Tags: windows, batch-file, server, ftp, backup

I have issue with backup folders from server to ftp (NAS). I was using Cobian backup, but after security updates Cobian started don't handle some files what earlier wasn't problem (doc,pdf or some type setup file). I tried change to .bat files script with scheduler help. I was using script

```
net use X: \\address\Backup /user:logins /p:no






for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a


md X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%"
md X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%"
md X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%"
md X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%"
md X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%"


net stop MSSQL$PAYPREMIUM
net stop ASANYs_labbis
net stop ASANYs_FinvaldaMaxiServer
net stop ASANYs_FinvaldaMaxiServern

robocopy C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.PAYPREMIUM\MSSQL\DATA X:\1\PAYPREMIUM\DATA /MIR /LOG:D:\LOG\log.txt

robocopy /mir C:\*\ X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%" /COPY:DAT /E /LOG:D:\LOG\log.txt

robocopy /mir C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.PAYPREMIUM\MSSQL\DATA\ X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%" /COPY:DAT /E /LOG:D:\LOG\log.txt

robocopy /mir C:\ProgramData\*\data\ X:\*\data_"%date:/=_%" /COPY:DAT /E /LOG:D:\LOG\log.txt

robocopy /mir G:\*_K\ X:\*\*_K_"%date:/=_%" /COPY:DAT /E /LOG:D:\LOG\log.txt

robocopy /mir G:\*\ X:\*\*_"%date:/=_%" /COPY:DAT /E /LOG:D:\LOG\log.txt




net start MSSQL$PAYPREMIUM
net start ASANYs_labbis
net start ASANYs_FinvaldaMaxiServer
net start ASANYs_FinvaldaMaxiServern

net use X: * /delete /Y
```

But robocopy and xcopy did not handled some situations. So after this I try use WinSCP script

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ftp://logins


put -preservetime E:\FILESERVER /disk1/ftp/SRV/FileServer_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%

exit
```

But even this did not handle the situation when from catalog tree with files from 60+GB only copy one folder without files that make trouble. Trouble that when you copy simple you get notifications about path long and another about that cant copy permissions pdf, doc, ppt files. So I need to make that pass this problems and copy as much that not have problem with path long and path long files that make error just skip.

Answer (score 1):

The long path issue you'll have to address by shortening the destination path name; sometimes `SUBST` can be used to help you get around that problem, if memory serves.  Something like:

```
NET USE X: \\server\dir
SUBST T: X:\subdir\subsubdir\subsubsubdir\anotherlongdir\blah
```

Cleanup:

```
SUBST T: /D
```

As to continuing to copy files after some files get error, I believe `robocopy /R:0 /W:0` will help, and `XCOPY /C` is its counterpart.